# Deploying project to google app engine successful but when visiting url shows error NOT_FOUND

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-mars

I am using eclipse mars with google plugin to deploy project to google app engine. My application can run locally without issues. When I deploy my project to my project that I created on appspot.com, making sure the project ID is set correctly, it deploys succesfully without issues. However, visiting the project id.appspot.com shows error NOT_FOUND.

Any help is appreciated.

------------ Deploying frontend ------------

```
Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7951301900869241602.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
    Initiating update.
    Cloning 3 static files.
    Cloning 36 application files.

Deploying:
    Uploading 1 files.
    Uploaded 1 files.
    Sending batch containing 1 file(s) totaling 1KB.
    Initializing precompilation...
    Deploying new version.
    Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
    Uploading index definitions.

Deployment completed successfully
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">

</web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/guestbook</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>sign</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>guestbook.SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-name>sign</servlet-name>

        <url-pattern>/sign</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Logs:

```
18:38:21.349
GET
404
204 B
12 ms
Chrome 53
/
 98.198.70.88 - - [04/Sep/2016:18:38:21 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 204 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36" "zipingguestbook.appspot.com" ms=12 cpu_ms=15716 cpm_usd=2.2798e-8 loading_request=0 instance=00c61b117cb25c5a8704a570f125a8aecbe66e4a7db0d1d95155df4b6198e0 app_engine_release=1.9.44 trace_id=0764e930015bad0d5bab7e025dd48a51
{
 metadata: {…}   
 protoPayload: {…}   
 insertId: "2016-09-04|15:38:26.362743-07|10.106.149.194|-1325158672"   
 log: "appengine.googleapis.com/request_log"   
 httpRequest: {…}   
 operation: {…}   
}

19:19:57.220
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

Comment: visiting the projectid.appspot.com shows error NOT_FOUND, to make it more clear.

Comment: What do you see in your app's logs? You might need to show the related app config/code as well. BTW - you can edit your question to add updates - comments might dissapear.

Comment: !ENTRY com.google.appengine.eclipse.core 1 0 2016-09-04 18:13:28.756
!MESSAGE Guestbook successfully deployed to Google App Engine

Comment: added config/code

Comment: Those are deployment logs - things look OK there. I was referring to your app's logs, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/. You can view them in the developer console: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs

Comment: Thanks Dan, I added one piece of the log, when I tried accesing my app.

Comment: OK, so you get a 404 on a request to the `/` path. Your post doesn't show how's that supposed to be handled in your app - the URL routing, the handler code, etc. (I'm just trying to help you on the path, I can't really offer very specific help in your case as I'm a python GAE user, not a java one). Many other things can lead to this behaviour as well - you'll need to narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks dan. I saw a new piece of info from the log:

19:19:57.220
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Comment: Did you try going to project id.appspot.com/sign ? This is the mapping you provided in your web.xml

Comment: The mapping /sign I can go to, I can also go to /guestbook, it's when I try going to /guestbook.jsp where it shows NOT_FOUND, yet I can go to it if I run it locally